# JMeter Testcases work only if they run in a single thread

Tags: multithreading, jsf, primefaces, jmeter, load-testing

I am currently trying to set up JMeter-load-tests for a JSF application. Everything is fine and I get the correct result if I use the standard "1 thread 1 repeat" - configuration. It also works with as many repetitions as I want, as long as it's a single thread.

As soon as I change the number of threads, for example using 4 threads at the same time, I get ViewExpiredException's and stuff like that. Feels like the viewstate gets lost somewhere, but I am unable to work out what it is since it works fine in a single thread. This does not happen with every request, some seem to work fine.

Scenario #1: A single thread and a any amount of repetitions - It works fine

Scenario #2: More than a single thread and any amount of repetitions - The server throws a ViewExpiredException on some (no pattern visible) requests.

Any tips? Google couldn't help. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I forgot to add: The viewstate seems to get sent as expected. There is never the default viewstate.

Comment: how does your server side identify a unique client? and do you properly configure these parameters to make sure each thread is a unique client?

Comment: What do you mean by "properly"? I am pretty sure it's a basic mistake, but could you elaborate? I will add details at work tomorrow.

Comment: "properly" would depend on how your app works, and that is what I don't know. Simplest example: client ID is in part identified by source IP, and since source IP is the same for all JMeter threads, it will consider it to be the same client.

Answer (score 0):

JSF applications are easy to load test if you have understood the basics of dynamic parameter correlations. Have you properly correlated the following dynamic parameters:

- javax.faces.ViewState

I suggest to use the following possible regular expressions: ($1$ template)

`\sname\s*?=\s*?"javax\.faces\.ViewState"[^^]*?\svalue\s*?=\s*?"(.*?)"[^^]*?>`

And:

`<update id="javax\.faces\.ViewState"><!\[CDATA\[(.*?)\]\]>`

You should extract those values from the responses, and reinject them into subsequent requests. There parameters are dynamically generated on each request.

With JMeter, it really hurts to perform correlation because they have to be done manually each time you record again you script. We managed to make this task a lot easier by implementing [Auto Correlation Rules](https://doc.octoperf.com/correlation/) on top of JMeter.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, have corrected the name of the parameter :)

Comment: Well, ViewState-extraction and -injection works fine with a single thread. That's not the issue. It does not work if I run multiple threads (and therefore requests) at the same time.

Comment: You have necessarly shared something like a cookie or a session header between users, because threads in JMeter are independent.

Comment: I actually share a cookie, but that one just contains the "level" (user, admin, etc) of the user. The application is embedded and login happens through the surrounding system. Other than that everything should be session-independent, as far as I understand JMeter (and I am definitely not a pro...). I found out that it seems to be a problem that there is not option to logout in the application, therefore I am now building a hidden page that just destroys the current session. It works with a higher "ramp-up"-time the more threads there are and seems to be a problem in the application itself.

Comment: Glad that you could go further :)

Comment: Thanks for the help though.